# jqGrid need 'enter' key to perform validation functions with inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid (pared-down example below) where I need rather complicated validation to be done as new rows are being selected, unselected, and (later) when the grid is saved. The built-in validation techniques weren't working well for my purposes (for legacy purposes, I need fairly fine-grained control over the behavior). I've got almost all of the problems fixed except for the 'Enter' key.

This is the "inline editing" demo, except notice the custom "onSelectRow" function...

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
  var lastsel
  jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid({        
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:['ID Number','Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via','Notes'],
    colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, sorttype:"int", editable: true},
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,editable: true },
      {name:'stock',index:'stock', width:60, editable: true},
      {name:'ship',index:'ship', width:90, editable: true},                       
      {name:'note',index:'note', width:200, sortable:false,editable: true}                      
              ],
    onSelectRow: function(id){
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                if (lastsel != undefined) {
                    jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel);
                    if ( ! myValidate(lastsel) ) {
                        jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('editRow', lastsel, true);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                lastsel = id;
            }
    },
    editurl: "clientArray",
    caption: "Sample"
  });
  var mydata2 = [
    {id:"12345",name:"Desktop Computer",note:"note",stock:"Yes",ship:"FedEx"},
    {id:"23456",name:"Laptop",note:"Long text ",stock:"Yes",ship:"InTime"},
    {id:"34567",name:"LCD Monitor",note:"note3",stock:"Yes",ship:"TNT"},
    ];
  for(var i=0;i<mydata2.length;i++)
    jQuery("#rowed5").addRowData(mydata2[i].id,mydata2[i]);
});

function myValidate(id) {
    var t = jQuery("#rowed5").jqGrid("getCell", id, 'note');
    if ( t.length > 5 ) {
        jQuery("#rowed5")
            .jqGrid('resetSelection').jqGrid('setSelection', id, false);
        alert('note is too long, max 5 char');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
<table id="rowed5"></table>
```

If you change row selections within the grid by using the mouse the field "notes" is validated. However, if you press the enter key to accept the row values... I can't figure out where to catch that event to insert my validation function. There doesn't seem to be an "onSaveRow" event or "before saveRow" event to catch.

It seems I need to either catch the "enter" key myself, or inject my code into the saveRow method

Note: I'm aware of the `beforeCellSave` event when using `cellEdit: true` but I don't *want* cell editing.

**Edit:** Now reflects Oleg's demo with my code largely removed:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        'use strict';
        var mydata = [
                {id: "12345", name: "Desktop Computer", note: "note",      stock: "Yes", ship: "FedEx"},
                {id: "23456", name: "Laptop",           note: "Long text", stock: "Yes", ship: "InTime"},
                {id: "34567", name: "LCD Monitor",      note: "note3",     stock: "Yes", ship: "TNT"}
            ],
            $grid = $("#rowed5"),
            numberTemplate = {formatter: 'number', align: 'right', sorttype: 'number', editable: true,
                searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'le', 'gt', 'ge', 'nu', 'nn', 'in', 'ni'] }},
            lastsel;

        function myValidate1 (value, colname) {
            if (value.length > 5) {
                return [false, " is too long for the column '" +
                               colname + "'\nMax 5 char is permitted"];
            } else {
                return [true, ""];
            }
        }

        $grid.jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            data: mydata,
            height: 'auto',
            colNames: ['ID Number','Name', 'Stock', 'Ship via','Notes'],
            colModel: [
              {name: 'id',    index: 'id',    width: 90,  editable: true, sorttype: "int"},
              {name: 'name',  index: 'name',  width: 150, editable: true},
              {name: 'stock', index: 'stock', width: 60,  editable: true},
              {name: 'ship',  index: 'ship',  width: 90,  editable: true},
              {name: 'note',  index: 'note',  width: 200, editable: true, sortable: false,
                  editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: myValidate1}}
            ],
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                var $this = $(this);
                if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                    if (lastsel != undefined) {
                        $this.jqGrid('saveRow', lastsel);
                    }
                    $this.jqGrid('editRow', id, true);
                    lastsel = id;
                }
            },
            editurl: "clientArray",
            caption: "Sample"
        });
    });
```

I removed the `myValidate` call and the return from the select handler.  The problem that remains though is that the demo relies only on the `editrules`/`custom_func` validation and it no longer works.  When I `return [false, ...]` from the handler the selection still succeeds and the new line is selected.  I need to keep the old line selected if the validation fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to use

```
editoptions: {maxlength: 5}
```

to restrict the max length of the input characters. For the validation you can use additionally [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules). If the example only the demo and you need some really complex validation you consider to use [custom validation rule](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example). For example

```
editrules: {custom: true, custom_func: myValidate1}
```

where

```
function myValidate1 (value, colname) {
    if (value.length > 5) {
        return [false, " is too long for the column '" +
                       colname + "'\nMax 5 char is permitted"];
    } else {
        return [true, ""];
    }
}
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ValidationInInlineEditing.htm).

Comment: The validating for length was just an example for posting to SO.   Editing the demo you provided as shown above, the problem now is that even though the validation fails, the new selection is allowed to happen.  In the original program, if the validation fails the selection reverts to the row where the failure occurred.

Comment: @clintp: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean under "the new selection is allowed to happen". The goal of validation is to hold editing till the user don't enter valid data. So the row will be in the *editing* mode and the saving of wrong data will be prohibited. Which row is selected is not important for the editing in the common case.

Comment: No problem, it's kind of unusual how this needs to work. How I need it to work is if the cell doesn't validate correctly, the row is thrown back into editing mode (or left in editing mode) and the new row selection is ignored.  It's not the jqGrid inline navigation model exactly.  But suggestions to work around it are still welcome.  :)

Comment: @clintp: You don't posted before about the changes on the question. Now I seems begin to understand what you want. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ValidationInInlineEditing1.htm). It skips to enter in the editing mode of the selected row if any other row stay not valid. If you would use `beforeSelectRow` instead of `onSelectRow` you can `return false` from the `beforeSelectRow` to prevent selecting of other row if another row is still in editing. See [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ValidationInInlineEditing2.htm).